# amazon connect in the Custom portal integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-connect

I want to bring the data and call portal to my own web pages.

Should i make an API call to my backend from AWS Lambda or is there any direct method from the amazon connect?

Can someone suggest some direction or some documentation/blogs for the same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Amazon Connect API from a lambda, your own backend or using a RESTful api. Please refer to [Amazon Connect docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html) for reference.